# Extract specific columns from SQL Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have the following table in Redshift:

```
Column 
Lant On h1 
Grent Off h3 
Hasard Varvey On h1 
Richie Unknown h1
```

I would like to have the following outcome:

```
Column 
On
Off
On
Unknown
```

Utilizing split_part(Column, ' ', 2) is not feasible as the third record would return Varvey instead of on. Is there any way that I could extract the desired values?

Comment: Is the desired part of the column string always the second from the right?  If so then count the number of spaces and use this as the "part" value in split_part().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) as you can apply a Regex pattern to match your use case.

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Lant On h1', '(On|Off|Unknown)');
select REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Grent Off h3', '(On|Off|Unknown)');
select REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Hasard Varvey On h1', '(On|Off|Unknown)');
select REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Richie Unknown h1', '(On|Off|Unknown)');
```

This would pick up the values that are provided within the regex pattern